# Dynamic SQL with embedded table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which does the job but instead of the `trans_inventory` (which is an ID of the location) I need to get the location_name.

This one is working to get the id

```
SELECT *  
FROM {TABLE} 
WHERE trans_product = 646 
ORDER BY trans_date2 DESC Limit 1
```

But I wonder if I can do it this way, somehow embed the location table, I have tried but below doesn't work

```
SELECT *, site_location.location_name
FROM site_trans 
cross join 
(select * 
 From site_location) 
site_location
WHERE trans_product=646 ORDER BY trans_date2 DESC Limit 1
```

Comment: What's the error u are getting? What's your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sl.location in the JOIN must be the site_location location id field name - I used locastion_id but it might be likely id as well. I used LEFT JOIN to avoid missing site_trans in case there is no matching location id.

```
SELECT s.*, sl.location_name
FROM site_trans AS s
LEFT JOIN site_location AS sl ON sl.location_id = s.location_id
WHERE s.trans_product=646 
ORDER BY s.trans_date2 DESC 
Limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much this is the answer indeed.